# Can two applications access the same record at once from same databse with READLOCK?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, locking, database-locking

I have a java application and when two instances of the application trying to start at once, i get the following error.This is mainly because both are accessing the same record.But isn't ReadLock is shared therefore multiple users can access it at one?

> database.DatabaseLockException: Database locked.  ErrorCode:'LOCKED' (Caused by com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock: wsrep aborted transaction) (vendorErrorCode: 1213) (problemStatement: `SELECT ID,Licence_Id,Installation_Id,Generation_Date,Valid_From,Expiry_Date FROM Licences WHERE (Valid_From <= ? AND Expiry_Date >= ?) ORDER BY Generation_Date DESC)`

Comment: Is it `LOCK` locked or just deadlocked due to a timeout? It could be `WRITE` locked. If you can avoid locking, that's usually for the best.

Comment: Two concurrent SELECT statements cannot result in LOCK error.

Comment: Your error message suggests you have a `Deadlock:` So something else is causing that, NOT 2 select statements